# Broadcast Reciever in android with Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED not working in background

Tags: android-broadcast

I am developing an android application in which I have to get the battery charge % through broadcast receiver and display a toast in background when battery is changed.
I have registered receiver and intent filer required to get the value.

It runs fine when app is opened but it does not provide value when app is closed.

Please suggest what should I do in order to run the toast with value in background when app is closed

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {
 private TextView batteryPercent;
 int level;
 private void getBatteryPercentage() {
 BroadcastReceiver batteryLevelReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
         context.unregisterReceiver(this);
         int currentLevel = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL,-1);
         int scale = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);
         level = -1;
         if (currentLevel >= 0 && scale > 0) {
             level = (currentLevel * 100) / scale;
         }
         batteryPercent.setText("Battery Level Remaining: " + level + "%");


         CountDownTimer cdt = new CountDownTimer(5000, 1000) {

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {          

            }

            public void onFinish() {

                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Level "+Integer.toString(level), 
                           Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              ;                     
            }

          }
          .start();
     }
 }; 
 IntentFilter batteryLevelFilter = new          IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
 registerReceiver(batteryLevelReceiver, batteryLevelFilter);
 }

 /* @Override*/
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     batteryPercent = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.batteryLevel);
     getBatteryPercentage();
}
```

> Blockquote

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the same Broadcast receiver registered in the Manifest with its own separate class
Like this.

```
<BroadcastReceiver
           android:name = "class name">
           <intent-filter>
                <action android:name = " your action here"/>
           </intent-filter>
</BroadcastReceiver>
```

In this case your action is `android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED` so the code would be

```
<BroadcastReceiver
           android:name = "class name">
           <intent-filter>
                <action android:name = "android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED"/>
           </intent-filter>
</BroadcastReceiver>
```

Hope this helps you